# What am I ..think fast?

Tags: riddle

> Something thing comes in..
>
> Something thing goes out..
>
> Some people press me..
>
> while others touch me..
>
> I die every few days but don't worry you can bring back me to life or you can take care that I don't die..
>
> You speak to me but I don't listen ..
>
> But when I speak although not my words, you listen to me..

What am I?

Comment: "Something thing" - is the double "thing" deliberate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are a

> Mobile phone

Something thing comes in..
Something thing goes out..

> Incoming and outgoing calls or messages

Some people press me..
while others touch me..

> Depending on whether you have an older key-press phone or a touchscreen.

I die every few days but don't worry you can bring back me to life or you can take care that I don't die..

> I think this refers to the phone battery dying unless you charge it.

You speak to me but I don't listen ..

> You speak into a mobile phone but it doesn't "listen"

But when I speak although not my words, you listen to me..

> It will be the words of the person calling you or receiving the call,

Comment: You're too fast :)

Answer (score 1):

You are (probably)

> a cell phone.

But this may end up being too broad.

> Something thing comes in..

> A signal, power, my inputs, my voice, ...

> Something thing goes out..

> Sound, a signal, etc

> Some people press me..
>   while others touch me..

> Buttons vs touch screen

> I die every few days but don't worry you can bring back me to life or you can take care that I don't die..

> Needs to be recharged

> You speak to me but I don't listen ..

> Yup

> But when I speak although not my words, you listen to me..

> Yup

Comment: Ninja'd by a minute!